# How to Add External JS libraries in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

i m using a template which have many js external files i want to use that template whole functionality but i dont know how to include js files in reactjs project

what i m doing now is adding this code in my public/index.html file but its not working

````
<script type="text/babel" src="javascript/vendors/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/babel" src="javascript/vendors/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/babel" src="javascript/vendors/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/babel" src="javascript/vendors/circle-progress.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/babel" src="plugins/rating/jquery.rating-stars.js"></script>
      <script type="text/babel" src="plugins/charts-c3/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/babel" src="plugins/charts-c3/c3-chart.js"></script>
      <script type="text/babel" src="plugins/sidebar/sidebar.js"></script>
      <script type="text/babel" src="plugins/horizontal-menu/webslidemenu.js"></script>
      <script type="text/babel" src="plugins/jquery-jside-menu-master/js/jquery.jside.menu.js"></script>
      <script type="text/babel" src="plugins/scroll-bar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/babel" src="javascript/custom.js"></script>
```
````

Answer (score 0):

ReactJS using virtual DOM, so you should not use external js, because they are all working with real DOM, will slow down your application, If you use it with React, you remove the best feature of React, you need to convert all library and using it like react way(import, require...).

I'm using several html templates for react project, they have a lot of external js files, but I only keep css, image, font.

Comment: but i still want to use it

Comment: There is no way to use them without modifying a lot of code, maybe it will not work as expected. If you're saving your time by using these js files, my suggestion is: use version for reactjs, or find an alternative library in react, and then re-write all javascript functions to your React app.

Comment: @Mubashir I'm very happy if you can show me what wrong?

Comment: i see a website who using external js in reactjs www.nouw.com